# How did I get additional language in my language selection?

Tags: windows-7, input-languages

I never added French language yet somehow it is selectable. Is this a bug or is it a feature (see image)?

[image: French language selection]

Comment: What have you researched or attempted to resolve this?

Comment: Thank you for editing my question to make it clearer.
I have just searched on google but could not find any similar things happeninng.

Comment: After restart the additional language was gone.